# Unity - How to move a user controlled animated gameobject programmatically?

Tags: unity, animation

I have a player controlled gameObject with an attached script and animator with it's related animations. It all works great.

However the gameObject is on screen immediately on level startup.

I want to have the gameObject start off-screen so that story dialog can be displayed first and once completed the player gameObject will move onto the screen and then come under the players control.

I have been able to create a separate animator state for the "off-screen to on-screen" animation and it can be triggered separately in code. But I can't work out the logic needed to get the gameObject to do what I want.

In the enclosed image the PaddleIdle state keeps the paddle off screen.
The PaddleStartup state moves the gameObjects position onto the screen.
Once on-screen, the PaddleNormal state is supposed to start the gameObjects normal animations and allow player control.

I have tried a default transition from PaddleStartup to PaddleNormal but it performs one "PaddleStartup" sequence and then there is nothing.

I know I am missing something either I am not configuring a transition correctly or I am not scripting this correctly, can someone advise me on things I might try?

[image: Code]
[image: States]
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Have you tried creating a trigger-controlled transition from PaddleIdle to PaddleStartup?

Answer (score -1):

You have not given enough info. But you can use something like this (the code may differ depending on the version):

```
...
if (this->sceneManager.currentScene == "boot") {
  this->_status = INVISIBLE;
}
...
...
If (this->_status == INVISIBLE) {
  this->player.playAnimation("invisible");
}
```

You can add an invisible animation in the `void Player::setupAnimations(...)` function, in which there are sprites with only a black background. The `this->_status = INVISIBLE;` statement means there is a global enumeration called `_status` like given below:--

In the file `globals.h`:

```
...
enum PlayerStatus {
  ALIVE, 
  DEAD,
  INVISIBLE
}
...
```

And, in the file 'player.cs' (for your player gameObject):

```
...
protected:
  PlayerStatus _status;
...
```

If the current scene is displaying your game's title then the `_status` will be `INVISIBLE`. and if the `_status` is `INVISIBLE`, the `"invisible"` animation will be played.

Hope that helped.